# Same row height for all table columns using elm-ui

Tags: elm, elm-ui

I cannot figure out how to obtain the same row height for every column when using `table` or `indexedTable` in elm-ui. Is this possible (without setting a fixed height) or should I resort to implementing my own table with `row` and `column`?

The following [ellie](https://ellie-app.com/fqVkxB97b7Za1) illustrates the issue.
This is the code used to build the table

```
bgcolor idx =
    (if modBy 2 idx == 0 then
        gray

     else
        white
    )
        |> Background.color

view model =
    indexedTable []
        { data =
            [ { f1 = "f11", f2 = "f12" }
            , { f1 = "f21", f2 = "f22" }
            , { f1 = "f31", f2 = "f32" }
            , { f1 = "f41", f2 = "f42" }
            ]
        , columns =
            [ { header = text "f1"
              , width = fill
              , view = \idx d -> el [ Font.size 30, bgcolor idx ] <| text d.f1
              }
            , { header = text "f2"
              , width = fill
              , view = \idx d -> el [ Font.size 15, bgcolor idx ] <| text d.f2
              }
            ]
        }
        |> layout []
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to accomplish this with plain HTML and CSS?

Comment: I thought this would output a `<table>`, but it actually does use `grid`. That's pretty silly from a semantic point of view, but that also means it should be feasible, I think, if you can get it to output the right `grid-template-rows` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `height fill` to each cell's attributes fixes your Ellie example:

```
        , columns =
            [ { header = text "f1"
              , width = fill
              , view =
                    \idx d ->
                        el
                            [ Font.size 30
                            , bgcolor idx
                            , height fill -- NEW!!!
                            ]
                        <|
                            text d.f1

              --
              }
            , { header = text "f2"
              , width = fill
              , view =
                    \idx d ->
                        el
                            [ Font.size 15
                            , bgcolor idx
                            , height fill -- NEW!!!
                            ]
                        <|
                            text d.f2
              }
            ]
```

[Fixed Ellie here.](https://ellie-app.com/frRHTDkngrNa1)